# How are lambda expressions bound to a class?

Tags: python

If I set up a class like below in Python, as I expect the lambda expressions created should be bound to the class A. I don't understand why when I put a lambda inside a list like in `g` it isn't bound.

```
class A(object):
  f = lambda x,y: (x + y)
  g = [lambda x,y: (x + y)]


a = A()

#a.f bound
print a.f
<bound method A.<lambda> of <__main__.A object at 0xb743350c>>

#a.g[0] not bound
print a.g[0]
<function <lambda> at 0xb742d294>
```

Why is one bound and not the other?

Comment: Do you mean `a.f` instead of `a.l`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`f` is bound because it's a part of the class as per the definition. `g` is not a method. `g` is a list. The first element of this list incidentally happens to be a lambda expression. That's got nothing to do with whether `g` is defined inside a class definition or not.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy "User-defined methods"

Answer (score 0):

If you want `g[0]` to be a bound method too, do:

```
class A(object):
  f = lambda x,y: (x + y)
  _ = lambda x,y: (x + y)
  g = [_]
```